# Current value not reflecting in reactjs select component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a custom Select in react. Whenever I try to select a value from the options it reflects old value only e.g I selected 4 from the dropdown handleChange functions will get the value 1 from e.target.value but the dropdown box will show the changed value '4'.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {selectValue:'1'};
    },
    handleChange:function(e){
        this.setState({selectValue:e.target.value});
        this.props.callbackParent(this.state.selectValue);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
         <select value={this.state.selectValue}
            onChange={this.handleChange} >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying get value(`selectValue`) from state(`this.state`) whereas it is not completed, in this case you can use callback as a second argument in [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate), like this

```
handleChange: function(e) {
  this.setState({selectValue:e.target.value}, function () {
    this.props.callbackParent(this.state.selectValue);
  });
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/23058/)

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly except the type error for props.callbackParent:

https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```